Passing arguments to eclipse through flatpak
I run eclipse on linux mint. The installation uses flatpak as an envelope for execution. The exact command is: /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=eclipse --file-forwarding org.eclipse.Java I want to pass the workspace path to eclipse and after googling, found that eclipse can take an argument specifying the workspace. Specifically, it is the -data argument, which takes a path to the workspace. So, I tried: /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command="eclipse -data <absolute path to workspace>" --file-forwarding org.eclipse.Java I quoted the whole command because when left out the quotes, flatpak complained that it did not recognize the -data flag. However, now I get the following error:
bwrap: execvp eclipse -data /home/dan/eclipse-workspace-minion: No such file or directory
I am guessing that quoting eclipse interferes with flatpak's search for the eclipse executable. (BTW: I checked and the directory /home/dan/eclipse-workspace-minion exists.) Can anyone advise me how to pass the -data argument to eclipse when it is executed through flatpak?

Before posting this question, I did a lot of searching on the internet for answers. After posting, I continued to search for an answer and have actually found one here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/flatpak/comments/lgfy5p/how_can_i_pass_arguments_to_a_flatpak_can_flatpak/
In this discussion is a reply by v_fv that states "... most Flatpak applications export a shortcut to run them in
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/"
It turns out the eclipse installation does this, so you can execute:
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/org.eclipse.Java -data <absolute path to workspace>
Alternatively, you can add
export PATH="/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:$PATH"
to .bashrc and then execute:
org.eclipse.Java -data <absolute path to workspace>

It turns out executing eclipse this way produces a bunch of chatter in the terminal session, but that doesn't interfere with the launch, which works perfectly.
I should mention this is on Linux Mint 21.3 (Ubuntu 22.04). This doesn't guarantee that it will work on other distributions of Linux.
